# Reject a promise and stop timeout on socket-io event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, es6-promise

I'm currently using the following function to simulate awaiting (sleep) in my Node.js server script.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

and I'm using it like below. When used in this way, executing the code below that line is paused until 20 seconds have been passed.

```js
await sleep(20000)
```

Now I want to **break this sleeping on a socket-io event**, but I can't figure a correct way out to do that.

I tried the following code, but it didn't break the sleep.

```js
// This object holds some properties
var meetings = {

}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) => {
    var t = setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    // add the function as a "meetings" object property value
    meetings[endSleep] = function(){
      clearTimeout(t)
      reject()
    }    
  });
}

// later, using socket-io
socket.on("end_sleep",function(){
  meetings["endSleep"]()
})
```

How can I get this functionality to work? all helpful suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output and how do you call the sleep method in relation to end_sleep event?

Comment: The above code has some syntax issues. After fixing them, it worked for me

Comment: @tbking no output in the terminal. It just waits 20 seconds as usual despite a socket event is triggered. end_sleep event is emitted from a html file

Comment: @tbking I didn't post some irrelevant parts of the code. It will be a great favour done, if you can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: `meetings[endSleep] = function(){` should be `meetings["endSleep"] = function(){`

Comment: @BenAston that's just a typo :-). The actual code has quotation marks around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case 'break' means 'early resolving', not rejecting. If you calling reject the await statement will throw an error and execution of the async function can be stopped (if try catch block is not used).
The code might look a little better::

```
const CPromise= require("c-promise2");
// cancellable sleep
function sleep(ms, signal) {
    return new CPromise((resolve, reject, {onCancel}) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        onCancel(() => clearTimeout(timer));
    }, {signal}).catch(() => {});
}

(async()=>{
    const sleeper= sleep(30000);
    socket.on("end_sleep",function(){
        sleeper.cancel();
    });
    await sleeper;
})();
```

or

```
const abortController= new CPromise.AbortController();

(async()=>{
    await sleep(30000, abortController.signal);
})();

socket.on("end_sleep",function(){
    abortController.abort();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to wrap this in a class which holds the state of both the timerId and the `reject` of the returned `Promise` and use them within a `cancel` method.

The below demonstrates this:

```js
class Sleeper
{
   wait(ms){
     return  new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        this.reject = reject;
        this.t = setTimeout(resolve,ms);
     });
   }
   
   cancel(reason){
    clearTimeout(this.t);
    this.reject(reason);
   }
}
var sleep = new Sleeper();

async function test(){
  
  try{
    await sleep.wait(5000);
    console.log("finished");
  }catch(e){
    console.log("cancelled:", e);
  }
}

document.querySelector("#cancel").addEventListener("click", () => {
   sleep.cancel("cancel button pressed");
});

test();
```

```html
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

I've added the ability to pass a cancel reason, might be useful.

---

In your code that would look like:

```
var sleeper = new Sleeper();

socket.on("end_sleep",function(){
  sleeper.cancel(); // pass a reason if you wanted.
})

// your code
await sleeper.wait(20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why this works, but I thought to note down what made it work.

Everything was solved when I used `resolve` instead of `reject` as follows.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) => {
    var t = setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    // add the function as a "meetings" object property value
    meetings[endSleep] = function(){
      clearTimeout(t)
      resolve()
    }    
  });
}
```

If someone can explain why it works this way, please feel free to edit this answer.